# How many times onCreateLoader() will be called?

Tags: android, performance, loader, android-loadermanager

I have two activities A & B. I have implemented Loaders in both activities as I will be needing same data in both activities.

`onCreateLoader()` method of both activities will be called every time or just at the time of loader creation ?

Example : If Activity "A" is called and loader is created then same loader will be exist in memory and when activity "B" is called, It will reuse the same loader but `onCreateLoader()` of activity "B" will be called ?

Comment: You can find out by adding Log statements to your project

Comment: Yes, Thats the problem Log methods are showing logs in both onCreateLoader() methods, My concern is whether theoretically it should invoke onCreateLoader() or not

Comment: If an old Loader was being used, then onRestartLoader() would be called, which should result in a call to onCreateLoader() according to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21253332/will-loadermanager-restartloader-always-result-in-a-call-to-oncreateloader. So it shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: If I call same loaders in 2nd activity with the exactly same procedure, Does it matter ? or do I need to take care of whether loader is already present or not

Comment: By same loader you mean same class or same Loader object that was created in the first activity  ?

Comment: Yes By using same loader, i.e by calling getLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this); in both activities

Comment: As long as you are creating and returning a new Loader object inside onCreateLoader(), in should be fine.